# Possible to use unittest-like fixtures in py.test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I really like `py.test`, but I am having lots of difficulty understanding how `funcargs` work.

Is it possible to use a command line argument or an extension to enable the use of something that performs a similar role to `unittest.TestCase.setUp` and `unittest.TestCase.tearDown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

py.test supports "normal" xunit method-based fixtures by default, see:

http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/xunit_setup.html

Alternatively you can subclass from unittest.TestCase and use .setUp/tearDown but the latter may be a bit limited.

Comment: Thanks! I was certain that this was possible, because I've heard you mention in your talks.

Comment: That link is stale, this one works: http://pytest.org/xunit_setup.html#xunitsetup